# How does System.Net.Sockets.Socket() use its parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

When creating a new instance of [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264899.aspx), you specify a [SocketType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.sockettype.aspx) and [ProtocolType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.protocoltype.aspx). I want a SocketType of Stream. In the description of the Stream member, it says, "stream uses the TCP ProtocolType." However, I can still specify a different ProtocolType manually of UDP, ICMP, IGMP, ...

I'm not sure how this works at lower layers though - If I were to do something like...

`new NetworkStream(new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Icmp))`

Would I be wrapping my stream in ICMP traffic (meaning stream data within ICMP headers)? Please provide as much information as possible so I might understand how this is actually working under the hood.

Comment: actually you are creating a new instance of your Stream, so there shouldn't be wrapped anything.

Comment: So you're suggesting in the example given, the "ProtocolType.Icmp" is basically thrown out/ignored?

Comment: Note the allowed exceptions for the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264899.aspx): "[`SocketException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx): The combination of *socketType* and *protocolType* results in an invalid socket." - you can't arbitrarily mix and match the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Socket constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264899.aspx) provides an explanation saying that "The combination of socketType and protocolType results in an invalid socket."

This means that nothing is done under the hood per se. It throws an exception and never makes it to the underlying winsock functions.